# JQuery listen for scroll on child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markdown:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper>
    <div id="content">
```

When I try and use JQuery to listen for scrolling on `#content` nothing happens:

```
$('#content').scroll(function(){
  console.log('Scrolling');
});
```

However, when I listen on the `window` for scrolling, it works fine:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log('Scrolling');
});
```

Can anybody tell me why and a way that I can avoid this and rather listen on `#content`?

Comment: content has overflow scroll?

Comment: There should be no problem. The code is correct. Can you show us the full html / css?

Comment: First event will work only if inside of #content is scroll ( overflow:scroll in css ) and Your are scrolling it, if You are scrolling window then this event will not fire.

Comment: When are you calling `$('#content').scroll(…)` – does the element already exist at that time?

Comment: Can you please try applying height to your <div id="content"> ??

Comment: Most probably thing that happens is that DOM is not completely loaded when you attach the event, so maybe the element doesn't exist. Your solutions: Or you wait to complete loaded DOM before attach event, or use delegation events (like `$(document).on('#content', 'scroll', function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

try this full html markup and learn from it? :)
parent will scroll if: its content is larger than it is...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#content').scroll(function(){
  console.log('content Scrolling');
});
$('#wrapper').scroll(function(){
  console.log('wrapper Scrolling');
});
});
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="border:solid thin black; height: 300px; width: 200px; overflow:scroll;">
    <div id="content" style="border:solid thin red; height: 500px; width: 100px; overflow:scroll;">
    <div style="width: 50px; height: 600px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
window.onload=function(){
$('#content').scroll(function(){
  console.log('Scrolling');
});
};
```